# Turtle Graphics : Repeating Squares Question

Tags: python

In this code I was suppose to repeat a 100 squares inside of a square.

```
import turtle

num_squares = 100

turtle.pendown()
side = side_unit = 5



for sq in range(1, num_squares + 1):
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(side)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(side)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(side)
    turtle.left(90)
    side = side_unit + 3 * sq 

    turtle.goto(0,0)                

turtle.done()
```

I got it to work but I'm having trouble understanding why it works regarding the line:

```
side = side_unit + 3 * sq
```

Why would multiplying `side_unit + 3 * sq` make a new square?

Answer (score 0):

To make this simpler to understand I would define a function for drawing a single square.

```
def draw_square(side_length):
    """ Draw a square with given side length and return to origin """
    for i in range(3):
        turtle.left(90)
        turtle.forward(side_length)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.goto(0, 0)
```

that simplifies the loop to:

```
for sq in range(1, num_squares + 1):
    draw_square(side)
    side = side_unit + 3 * sq
```

A square with side length `side` is drawn every loop. since `sq` increments by 1 every time the loop iterates, `side_unit + 3 * sq` gets 3 larger every iteration. You are setting `side` (which is the square's side length) to this, which means that the square's side length will increase by 3 every iteration.